# Why is my segue being performed?

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS app, I have a log in `Button` to go from one `viewController` to another, which uses the following function:

```
@IBAction func logInButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if loggedIn == true {
        // user is signed in
        print("A user is logged in.")
        uid = user.uid
        self.currentUser(uid)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("logIn", sender: sender)
    } else {
        print("No current user.")
        let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation( keyPath:"transform" )
        anim.values = [
            NSValue( CATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-10, 0, 0 ) ),
            NSValue( CATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation( 10, 0, 0 ) )
        ]
        anim.autoreverses = true
        anim.repeatCount = 2
        anim.duration = 7/100
        self.passwordTextField.layer.addAnimation( anim, forKey:nil )
        self.welcomeTextLabel.hidden = false
        self.welcomeTextLabel.text = "Please sign in first"
    }
}
```

There's a function which runs within `viewDidLoad()` that updates the `loggedIn` value. I've tested this function when `loggedIn == false` (based on console output), and the app crashes based on code that executes on the subsequent `viewController`. I know why it crashes (no user data) but I don't know why the segue is being performed at all.

If you need more code to diagnose please ask.

Comment: Maybe you made "show" segue from logInButton to next view controller and forgot about it? This segue work without any additional code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your storyboard you need to create the segue between two view controllers instead of button to DestinationViewController.

Please remove that segue and create one segue from your LoginViewController to your DestinationViewController.